# OracleDataReader GetDouble ошибка cast is not valid

Tags: c#, oracle

Добрый день!
Видел много вопросов по этому поводу но ответа так и не нашёл

вот мой код

```
connection.Open();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
string sql="select  t2.NAME, Round((cast(localtimestamp as date)  - cast(t4.CREATED as date))*24*60,2) ,t3.NAME,localtimestamp  from MFSTRANSPORTORDER  t1 left join MFSTRANSPORTUNIT t2 on t2.ID=t1.TRANSPORTUNIT_ID left join MFSSTORAGELOCATION t3 on t3.ID=t2.STORAGELOCATION_ID  left join MFSTRANSPORTORDERREQUEST t4 on t2.ID=t4.TRANSPORTUNIT_ID where t3.NAME is NOT NULL";

command.CommandText = sql;

OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var lst = new List<Data>();
if (reader.HasRows)
     {
    while(reader.Read()){
    var row = new Data();
    row.Name = reader.GetString(0);
    if(!reader.IsDBNull(1))
    row.Time = reader.GetDouble(1);
    row.Place = reader.GetString(2);
    row.dt = reader.GetDateTime(3);
}
int g = lst.Count;
Data []temp=new Data[g];
temp = lst.ToArray();
}

connection.Close();
```

В строке запроса меня интересует второй столбец

```
Round((cast(localtimestamp as date)  - cast(t4.CREATED as date))*24*60,2)
```

При выволнении

```
row.Time = reader.GetDouble(1);
```

появляется ошибка

```
SystemInvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid
```

В этом поле должно быть число вида 2,45

Как убрать эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет того, чтобы узнать настоящий тип значения, а потом вызвать соответствующий метод?

```
reader.GetFieldType(1)
```

Возможно, там лежит decimal:

```
reader.GetDecimal(1)
```

Comment: Действительно decimal. Благодарю!

Comment: @user3216530 не за что!